# Creating required files in gocd

Tags: go-cd

I am aware that you can use environment variables in a pipeline, but is there a way to create necessary files (application.properties, config.xml, or whatnot) that are (usually) not included in the source repository?

My current workflow is to create a shell script that creates the environment configuration files and run it as a task. It's cumbersome and unintuitive, but it works. Is there not a UI or plugin for this? I think using configuration files is common practice.